# Getting random List output

Tags: c#

I have this code bellow and I need to read one line of a text file and get that one line written out in a random order from the differend lines in the text file.
How do I do that?

I have tried with the Next() but does not seem to capture all variables in the one line of my text file
Here is the code:

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public class Biblotekarie
    {

```
    public void inläsning()
    {



    }

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<string> Spara = new List<string>();



    string[] animals2 = new string[] { "Författare Pippi långstrump, Roman, Årstyp"
        , "Författare Pippi långstrump, Roman, Årstyp"
        , "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "sat" };

    public static Random rng;


    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\razer\Desktop\test.txt", Encoding.Default, false);
        string item = "";
        while ((item = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            Spara.Add(item);
        }
        //Spara.Add(animals2);
        rng = new Random();

        foreach (string a in Spara)
        {
            string[] vektor = a.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            int index = rng.Next(0,4);

        foreach (string item in Spara)

        {

            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(item[index]);

        }



    }

    private void SökRuta(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Your list has only one element in it, so there's no way to "randomly arrange" the list. The code you posted also attempts to add an index to a string, which will simply concatenate the string with the text representation of the index (e.g. `"two0"`). It does not help that your code example is cluttered/obfuscated by the inclusion of seemingly irrelevant WinForms code. Please read [mcve] and [ask]. Make sure your question states clearly and precisely what the actual output of the code is, and what output you desire instead.

Comment: I have now edited the topic, please see

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `rng` again to get a random item within the array

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(item[rng.Next(0, 2), rng.Next(0, 2)]);
```

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem now I need this help, random seem to not be able to become 2 dimensional here is the code:

Comment: @realme: If you need help with a separate issue, that should be in a new post. One question per post, please.

Comment: Yes, I need to make corrections here with you guys before I can move on to create a new post

Comment: what I need is to add streamreader filetext to an array. how do I do that?

Comment: `how do I do that?` In a new post @realme.